# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app' when trying absolute imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory-structure

I have been trying to import files into my *main.py* file by using imports from the sources root.
Here is a pic of my file structure...

[image: file_structure_screencap]

I am simply using source root imports to try and import *seed.py* into my *main.py* file. but keep getting this error message.

```
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'**
```

This makes no sense to me as my app is a module and has its own init file. Im not too sure If i have something incorrect in my file structure or if it is just pycharm being buggy. But i dont see a reason why this import shouldnt work.

here is a code snippet of the import statement I am using

```
from app.bitcoinBackend.seed import *
```

any ideas??

Comment: You need ```__init__.py``` in ```bitcoinBackend```, ```frontEnd```, and any other directories with modules you'll want to import from.

Comment: Adding to kendfss answer, here is a refresher on python packages from the official docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try move your main.py to the root folder of app and just call bitcoinBackend.seed import *. Because your main is in a subfolder of app.

Comment: I managed to fix the bug, this solution helped. The file restructure you suggested better fits

Answer (score 0):

Okays so the solution i found involved moving *main.py* out of the *frontend* module back into the *app* directory. Here is an image of the full restructure.

[image]

next you had to select a directory as *sources root* I haven't looked into it too much, but when I correctly selected the sources root, all sub dirs changed into having the appropriate module symbol. (you can see this is *app* and *bitcoinBackend*)

I selected the *teamSoftwareProject* as the sources root. There are two ways of doing this one way involves

1. right clicking the directory you want to set as sources root
2. selecting *Mark Directory As*
3. and then choosing *sources root*

Here is an image

[image: sources root]

The other method is

1. Selecting file -> Settings
2. Choose project structure
3. Then select your sources root folder
4. Click Apply and then Ok

Here is an image of this method.
[image: sourcesrootmethod2]

Finally I added ***init**.py* files to all other sub dirs

Then importing from the project root worked.

```
from app.bitcoinBackend.seed import *
```